# Is the use of 'unless' in 'Unless the earth had a moon, there wouldn't be any tides' correct?

Tags: grammaticality

> Unless the earth had a moon, there wouldn't be any tides.

I am confused with the use of 'unless' in this sentence.
The sentence is taken from a test question. Please explain it to me.

Answer (score 1):

It is a strange one, as you can understand the meaning, but would be better written as "If the Earth did not have a moon, there wouldn't be any tides." The word *unless* tends to be used to describe a sentence structured as:

> "Unless X is true, Y will not be true."

Or

> "Y will not happen unless X happens."

In your example, you could restructure the sentence to say:

> "There wouldn't be any tides unless the Earth had a moon."

However, this will not usually be considered correct because the word "unless" is not generally used to speak of known facts. The Earth does have a moon, so it would not make much sense to say that "something won't happen unless the Earth has one". It makes more sense to say in this instance:

> "There would be no tides if the Earth had no moon."

This could also be structured more similarly to your example:

> "If the Earth had no moon, there would be no tides."

Comment: I think you mean that "unless" is not generally used to talk about known facts. It is usually used to speak of hypothetical situations such as "Unless you pay me, I will not drive you to the airport."

Comment: In this case I was referring more to the hypothetical situation of the moon not existing, but yes, that is more clear. Feel free to edit my answer to make that sound more clear if you like.

Answer (score 0):

The word "unless" was originally the prepositional phrase "on lesse" which means "on a less condition" or "if it were less than true". Thus the sentence means:

> If it were less than true that the Earth has a moon, there would be no tides.