# Conditional type

Tags: grammar, conditional-constructions

[**Source**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/101758/37009)

I have seen a sentence as following.
"If the earth did not have a moon, there wouldn't be
any tides."
I wanted to know whether condition type can use
or not for the real situation.
Please explain it to me.

Comment: Please read [**this link**](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-English-Punctuation-Correctly). **This way , is wrong .  "** A space is used only after a period and a comma, never before it. Can you tell us whether you have a **"** character on your keyboard?

Comment: Thanks a lot  for correcting  my serious mistake. Later, I will be careful with my typing.

Comment: Your questions will be much easier to read if you use correct punctuation! Remember this, too: **only one space between each word.**

Comment: I'm typing on a phone.So, my commas are of a little difficult to type .

Comment: Plz,also answer my question .